# How is almost sure convergence defined without reference to the underlying probability measure space?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose I have some "leisurely defined" (real-valued) random variables $X_n, X$ - by this I mean no reference is made to the underlying probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ acting as the domain space of our random variables. Now suppose I'd like to prove that $X_n$ converges to $X$ almost surely. The definition, as I understand it, is
$$
\text{Pr}(\{\omega\in\Omega\ :\ \lim_n X_n(\omega) = X(\omega)\}) = 1
$$
which we write more succinctly as $\text{Pr}(\lim_n X_n = X) = 1$.

I don't really see how to do this without reference to the formal definition of our random variables. The expression $\lim_n X_n = X$ doesn't really mean anything (at least to me) when we just view our random variables as "things which can take on any number of values with certain probabilities."

For instance if $X^i$ were iid standard normal variables, and $X_n := \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X^i$, what would it mean to say $X_n\to 0$ almost surely? It's not as if the values $X_n$ takes on somehow "converge" to zero. We can't appeal to $X_n$'s distribution ($N(0, 1/n)$) and say this is what converges to zero, as this would be *convergence in distribution*. Nor can we appeal to $X_n$'s tail probabilities, $\text{Pr}(|X_n| > \epsilon)\to0$, as this would be *convergence in probability*. How could we check $X_n\overset{a}{\to} 0$, without writing down $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$?

It occurred to me that we can check whether
$$
\text{Pr}\left(\bigcap_n\bigcup_m\bigcap_{k\ge m}\left\{|X_k - X| < \frac1n\right\}\right) = 1
$$
which makes no reference to $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$, and perhaps we could use the Borel-Cantelli lemmas to simplify this further (though we might need to know that the events are *independent*), but this is still rather cumbersome in my opinion compared to just knowing the probability space beforehand.

Comment: Do you have similar objections to probabilities of events involving more than one random variable, like $P(X<Y)$? Or is it the fact that there are infinitely many that you find problematic? In both cases we need a [joint distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution), which indeed requires that the variables are defined on the same probability space.

Comment: The set of all $\omega$ on which $X_n(\omega)$ converges to $X(\omega)$ is an *event* in the $\sigma$-algebra ${\cal F}$. We say that $X_n\to X$ $P$-almost surely iff the probability of that event is one. I don't see how we can possibly do this without referring to $P$.

Comment: "It's not as if the values  takes on somehow "converge" to zero."  Yes, this is exactly what it means, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} X_n(\omega) = 0$ (for a set of $\omega$ in $\Omega$ that forms a set  that has probability 1). Even if there is no explicit mention of $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$, that probability space is still assumed to exist.

Comment: Your union/intersection statement is backwards, it should be $$P[\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}\cup_{m=1}^{\infty} \cap_{k\geq m} \{|X_k-X|<1/n\}]=1$$ with that event meaning "For all $n$, there is an $m$ such that for all $k\geq m$ we have $|X_k-X|<1/n$"

Comment: @Michael Thanks for pointing that out, must've gotten it mixed up when writing it down. The sense I get from the comments is that "no, there isn't a way to do it without the underlying space." I'd just like to see for my own benefit, how would you prove that my example $X_n$ converges almost surely to $0$?

Comment: Your example is not much different from asking how to prove the law of large numbers for i.i.d. random variables $\{X_i\}$ with mean zero and variance 1. With $M_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ the main idea is (1) Prove $E[M_n]=0$ and $E[M_n^2]=1/n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$; (2) Show  for all $\epsilon>0$ that $P[|M_n-0|\geq \epsilon] \leq 1/n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$; (3) Show for all $\epsilon>0$ that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P[|M_{i^2}-0|\geq \epsilon]<\infty$, thus by Borel-Cantelli $M_{i^2}\rightarrow 0$ almost surely; (4) Show $M_i\rightarrow 0$ almost surely.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the comprehensive answer, it's not quite what I was expecting. It just sounds like the answer is that it's not as easy to check for almost sure convergence as it is to check for the other types of convergence. That is, if you'd want to circumvent reference to the probability space, you'll need to be clever.

Comment: @Michael I'm coming from a very naive place here, all my life I've only worked with random variables as "things with pdfs and cdfs", I'm not really attuned to the idea of taking a random variable as the function (say, if $X$ has cdf $F$, we could consider $X$ as the function $F^{-1} : [0, 1]\to\mathbb{R}$ w/ Lebesgue measures). Convergence in distribution/probability I can verify while remaining in my happy playpen of "random variables as things that are sometimes one number and sometimes a different number", but I guess almost-sure convergence will require I abandon my puerile predilections.

Comment: It is not as if "everything becomes easy once you introduce $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$." The law of large numbers is a deep and hard result and its proof is not trivial, explicitly introducing $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ does nothing to simplify it. You may be interested in the following sufficient condition for an arbitrary sequence of random variables (not necessarily independent):  **Lemma:** A sequence of random variables $\{Y_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to a constant $c$ almost surely if for all $\epsilon>0$ we have $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P[|Y_n-c|>\epsilon]<\infty$$

Comment: @Michael That's closer to what I was looking for, thanks! Though it is only a sufficient condition, it's something I can sink my teeth into (from the naive perspective). I think there's a little bit of a disconnect in the comments which we could reconcile if speaking in person, because I was indeed trying to suggest the law of large numbers was non-trivial - we were on the same side of that coin. Nonetheless I think I've gotten pretty much what I asked for, thanks a lot for chatting with me!

Comment: I'll reiterate my comment that if you understand joint distributions (even "naively" without the measure theory), you're most of the way there. The point is that the joint distribution of a set of RVs carries a lot more information than the collection of their individual marginal distributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer summarizes my comments: There is always some probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$, even if the problem does not explicitly say so.

Here is a useful sufficient condition for convergence almost surely that works for a sequence of arbitrary random variables (not necessarily independent).  The lemma works more generally for convergence to a random variable $Y$, but I consider convergence to a constant $c$ for simplicity.

**Lemma:** Let $\{Y_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of random variables (all on the same probability space). Suppose there is a real number $c$ such that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P[|Y_n-c|>\epsilon] < \infty \quad \forall \epsilon>0$$
Then $Y_n\rightarrow c$ almost surely.

---

The above lemma is so useful that it is the standard way of proving the law of large numbers. Indeed, suppose $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are i.i.d. with finite mean and variance.  Define $m=E[X_n]$ and $\sigma^2=Var(X_n)$ for all $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$. Define
$$M_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \quad \forall n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$$

- You can use Chebyshev to show that $P[|M_n-c|>\epsilon]\leq \frac{\sigma^2}{\epsilon^2n}$ for all $n \in \{1, 2, 3,...\}$ and so the above lemma directly implies $M_{n^2}\rightarrow c$ almost surely. Some more details are needed to show that $M_n\rightarrow c$ almost surely (you would need to show $M_n$ does not significantly change between perfect squares $n=i^2$ and $n=(i+1)^2$).
- Assuming a finite fourth moment, so that $E[(Y_n-c)^4]=\mu<\infty$ for all $n$,  you can show $P[|M_n-c|>\epsilon]\leq \frac{1}{\epsilon^4}\cdot O(1/n^2)$ and so the above lemma directly implies $M_n\rightarrow c$ almost surely.

Both of the bullets above use the fact
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}<\infty$$